# When Do Quests Cycle on HearthStone?

Tags: hearthstone

In HearthStone I can only have 3 active quests at a time. When do I have to have completed one of them in order to receive a new daily quest?

I'm on EST, and I've waited till Midnight, 1AM, and last night I waited all the way till 3AM. Each time I still had a new daily quest the next morning.

I guess I'd also like to know, if I happened to be awake at such a time as the quests cycled, would I need to restart HearthStone to see the new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where you live, maybe you are not synced with the reset timezone :

> Daily quests are reset at 1 AM Pacific time.

And no you don't need to restart Hearthstone to get your new quest.
source : 
http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest[enter link description here](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest)